# How can I make post view count editable?

Tags: views

In the admin panel, under posts, I see all posts with their view counts next to them. How can I make the view count editable?

I am working on certain things that will kick in when a post reaches 100 views for example, and I want to set it manually for testing purposes.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: You need to edit the *function* that displays the view count, which is likely from a third-party plugin you've added.

Comment: Ah I see, so Wordpress doesn't do post view count by default? I am using a theme, but I thought the post view count was a native wordpress function. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Any kind of analtyics is _definitely_ not a core feature, it is way too resource intensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting an answer so I can close this. It seems the post view counter I see is part of my theme, not a core feature of Wordpress as I thought.